# Android getIntent().getExtras() returning null sometimes

Tags: android, android-intent, android-bundle

I was going through Crashlytics logs for my app and found that there is a NullPointerException on some devices because getIntent().getExtras() is returning null.

This behavior is seen only on a few devices and I am not able to reproduce this bug. I know that I can check in the activity if the Bundle is null and prevent the NullPointerException but I was more interested in finding out the root cause for this behavior.

Edit:

Source -

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Cursor c = (Cursor) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SelectedTopicActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("topicId", c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(AppContract.TopicsEntry._ID)));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Destination -

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_selected_topic);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    topicId = bundle.getLong("topicId");
    ...
}
```

If the cursor were null, I would have got the error in the source itself. I don't think the field in the cursor is null, otherwise the item won't be there in the list in the first place.

Comment: add some code related to the crash.

Comment: where is your code

Comment: put something to look upon so that we can find the exact problem.

Comment: I've added my code in the edit.

Comment: @prempal, do u have any news about this issue? I have the same problem... 3 years since you write.. :(

Comment: @xcesco I do not have access to the original codebase anymore but I just re-read the question and still can't think of any logical explanation as to why this might be happening.

Comment: @prempal, I think that this problem is due to the fact sometimes (maybe when user pushes back button) the OS launch the activity without the original Intent data. I will investigate and wrote here if I will found any solution or explanation about it.

Comment: @xcesco yes, I realized the same thing, the problem is the OS clear intent data sometimes, do you know a solution for this problem?

Comment: I'm sorry @hvar90, the problem is still here. Luckily it happens to a small group of users.