# Android passing parameters using Bundle is returning null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-bundle

I pass a parameter to my new activity in android:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,InOccasion.class);
intent.putExtra("key",key); //I've checked an seen that in this activity "key" isn't null
this.startActivity(intent);
```

As I said, `key` in this block isn't null.

However, when I retrieve it:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
if (b!=null)
  key = b.getString("b");
```

`key` is `null` and is causing a NullPointerException. However, I'm sure `key` isn't null. And yes, I am calling from the correct activity.

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38498499/android-getintent-getextras-returning-null-sometimes) but it's unanswered and mine is ALWAYS null.

Comment: It's a good habit to use `public static final String` values to keep your keys consistent across the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting they key name `"key"` and getting `"b"`. Get the right key i.e. `"key"`

Answer (score 1):

You are passing data to the `intent` not the `Bundle`. When you write data as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, InOccasion.class);
intent.putExtra("key", key); // key must be a String object
```

Get it as following:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
key = intent.getStringExtra("key");
```

Comment: Bundles are inside of intents. You can inspect the Android source code to see that `getStringExtra` just goes into the Bundle

Comment: See here. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/content/Intent.java#5059

Comment: @cricket_007 yup...i was wrong all along.!..Quick question - Whats the suggested way of handling my answer...its blatantly wrong...should I delete it or make an edit that its wrong...?

Comment: It'll still work ;) Just the problem with the question was the wrong key.